# What does !# (reversed shebang) means?

Tags: bash, scala

From this link: http://scala.epfl.ch/documentation/getting-started.html

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

I know that `$0` is for the script name, and `$@` for all argument passed to the execution, but what does `!#` means (google `bash "!#" symbols` seems to show no result)?

does it mean exit from script and stdin comes from remaining lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of scala itself, not bash. Note what's happening: the `exec` command *replaces* the process with `scala`, which then reads the file given as `"$0"`, i.e., the bash script file itself. Scala ignores the part between `#!` and `!#` and interprets the rest of the text as the scala program. They chose the "reverse shebang" as an appropriate counterpart to the shebang.

To see what I mean about `exec` replacing the process, try this simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ls
echo hello
```

It will not print "hello" since the process will be replaced by the `ls` process when `exec` is executed.

Reference: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/manual/html/scala.html

Answer (score 2):

A side comment, consider multiline script,

```
#!/bin/sh
        SOURCE="$LIB1/app.jar:$LIB2/app2.jar"
        exec scala -classpath $SOURCE -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Also note `-savecompiled` which can speed up reexecutions notably.